# How to roll back in windows Service?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, windows-services

I have a windows service which when start goes to the path which i define and collect a list of files and each file have records in it which i insert in database(Oracle).My problem is if this database gets down or if there is some exception how will i roll back previous record which inserted from the file..
For Example

i have 10 files each file has 5 records
when parsing 7th file there is some kind of exception on the 4th record like(db down or anything) i want to roll back previous 3 records which was inserted from 7th file, is it possible?

My code is here..

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    timer1 = new Timer();
    this.timer1.Interval = 30000;
    this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer_tick);
    timer1.Enabled = true;

    Upload.WriteErrorMessage("Service Started");

}

private void timer_tick(object sender,ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    SwiftParser.Parse();
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    Upload.WriteErrorMessage("service stoped");
}
```

the method where i uploading data:

```cs
Upload obj = new Upload();
var files = db.SWIFT_FILES.Select(x => x.LASTFILENUMBER).Max();
int sFile = Convert.ToInt32(files);
int sf1 = sFile;
while (true)
{
    string flName = @"D:\Projects\Recon\Nostro\swift\" + sFile.ToString("00000000").Trim() + ".swf";
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(flName))
    {
        obj.SwiftParse(flName);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
    sFile++;
}
```

In swift parse i just parse file and collect data from it and save in database it was actually a long method so i dont want to make mess here

in short
i make a object of table and save in it

```
for(int i=0; i<length of record; i ++)
{
    SwiftTable sw = new SwiftTable();
    sw.acc_no = from file i get acc no;
    sw.amount= ......................;
    sw.bank=.........................;
    db.Add.SwiftTable(sw);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Please tell me what are the workarounds for this or any suggestion will be help full.
I am using Oracle databse and c# windows service and Entity framework 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to put your `db.SaveChanges()` call outside the file loop. The other way is to use a transaction, something like this:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Connection.Open();

using (System.Data.Common.DbTransaction transaction = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Connection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
    {
        try
        {
            using (db)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<length of record; i ++)
                {
                    SwiftTable sw = new SwiftTable();
                    sw.acc_no = from file i get acc no;
                    sw.amount= ......................;
                    sw.bank=.........................;
                    db.Add.SwiftTable(sw);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am getting InvalidoperationException saying the connection is not open..any idea? your solution looks good  @JanneP

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer to include the connection opening.

Comment: Another exception is Dbcontext has been disposed

Comment: It should work if you have a non-disposed context. Test it by creating the context just before opening connection and remove the using -part of the code. That way you always keep your context alive. Just make sure you get rid of it later.

Comment: Thankx man..hey what if i don't remove using? it is working fine without removing using and where should i make my context dispose?

Comment: It depends on your scenario. I usually create and dispose the context at a higher level, so I can possibly reuse the same context for different processes. It also encourages unit testing to keep the context alive for all requests, so you could just mock the context and not worry about creating it later on.